# fixed render() must be called with a dict, not a Context but can't seem to render the variable in template why? django

Tags: python, django, email, dictionary, warnings

I am using the built in email system in django but then now I get such warning..

`RemovedInDjango110Warning: render() must be called with a dict, not a Context`

my code used to be `get_template(html_template).render(Context(body['ctx']))`

I already fixed it by doing this

`get_template(html_template).render({Context(body['ctx'])})`

but after I fixed it, somehow I cannot call the variable needed in my email template anymore.

`body['ctx']` actually contains something such as

```
{'type': 'type1', 'field': 'field1}
```

before, when I was still using the warning way to send emails, in the email template I can just use `{{type}}` or `{{field}}` but now after I fixed the warning, I cannot call the variable anymore.  I tried changing code into `get_template(html_template).render({'content': Context(body['ctx'])})` this still didn't work, in email template then I tried `{{content}}` I would then get something like this `[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'type': 'type1', 'field': 'field1'}]`

so I thought I can call the type variable by doing `{{ content.1.type }}` but still getting nothing.

can someone please give me an idea what I might be doing wrong or what else I can try here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `get_template(html_template).render(body['ctx'])`??

Comment: If Fazil's recommendation fails, you can see that `content` is a list of dicts, the second of which is the one you want, so : `{{context[1]['type']}}` should also work, although I'm not sure how dynamic `context` is in your case for this to remain a stable lookup.

Comment: @FazilZaid oh gosh, thx thx didn't know this would work too~ thx thx a lot

Comment: @JacobIRR I did try `context[1]` but then wouldn't let me that's why I searched up and saying in template use `context.1` which didn't work either :(

Comment: Would you like me to post it as an answer, then?

Comment: @FazilZaid yes of course, I was gonna say that.  So I can give you a check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, `body['ctx']` is already is a dictionary, you only need to just pass it in the `render()` function.

```
get_template(html_template).render(body['ctx'])
```